# Letter "a" at the beginning of every request using built in PHP server with laravel causing Unexpected EOF

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

So, yesterday all was fine but today all every time a load a page a letter a briefly appears in the top left. Also, I use InterventionImage with some of my images, so I am not directly loading an image file and this a has broken those (http://prntscr.com/am4xov). But I also noticed that this mysterious a also appears at the begging of composer commands (http://prntscr.com/am4y37). When I load one of these images in a new tab I get the following error: `Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)`
I am totally stumped and would appreciate any help at all! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have accidentally typed a random 'a' in a file. Look through your recent files opened or do a Find in file to find it, or look at the full error and it should list the file that the error is occurring in and then try to find the 'a'.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so as it is showing up on composer commands and I haven't touched any composer related files.

Comment: And you wouldn't have to have edited something directly in composer. Composer on Laravel from what I am reading in it's files uses some Laravel files. The most likely one might be /app/helper.php have you edited the Helper.php function lately?

Comment: I reverted to a previous commit and it no longer happnes. I checked through all the change I have made since that commit and cannot find the elusive a. However since this commit I have run composer update, so I suspect it could be a problem with an updated package. This is the list of updated packages: http://prntscr.com/am5rsn Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: It was at the beginning of my routes.php file... -_-